# Spinner Dropdown CheckedTextView Autoscroll

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, checkedtextview

I am trying to use a Spinner filled with long strings which should autoscroll horizontally.

So I wrote a custom Adapter which uses my own dropdown layout:

Layout:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="50"
android:singleLine="true" />
```

In my Adapter I overwrite the getDropDownView Method:

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if (convertView == null) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext());
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.scrolling_list_item, null);
    }

    return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

Any Idea why my CheckedTextView just stands still without autoscrolling?